# How to multiply two vectors (kets) in qiskit?

Tags: qiskit, programming, quantum-state, ibm-q-experience, circuit-construction

Hi does anyone know how i could write a program to get the product of something like |1>|0>|0>?

Comment: Do you mean the tensor product? This can be done as you can use the "statevector simulator". The qubits can be prepared to the desired state $|\psi\rangle$. Then the total output statevector may be the desired output

Comment: What sort of multiplication do you have in mind? Tensor product? Inner product? Outer product?

Answer (score 1):

### Create computational basis state circuit

With qiskit, you can do it like this:

```
from qiskit.circuit  import QuantumCircuit 
def create_computational_basis_state(basis_state: str):
        qc = QuantumCircuit(len(basis_state))     
        for i, bit in enumerate(basis_state):
            if int(bit) == 1: qc.x(i)
        print(qc)
        return qc
```

So for example:

```
qc = create_computational_basis_state('101')

     ┌───┐
q_0: ┤ X ├
     └───┘
q_1: ─────
     ┌───┐
q_2: ┤ X ├
     └───┘
```

---

### Extract the state vector

And if you want to get the vector/array of this state (the vector resulting from the tensor product) you can do the following:

```
from qiskit import Aer, execute
from qiskit.quantum_info import Statevector
backend = Aer.get_backend("statevector_simulator")
result = execute(qc, backend=backend, shots=1).result()
print('State Vector:', result.get_statevector() )

State Vector: [0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 1.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j]
```

Answer (score 0):

In Qiskit you can easily do tensor product of two states using `^` operator as follows:

```
from qiskit.quantum_info import Statevector

state1 = Statevector.from_label('++')
state2 = Statevector.from_label('--')

# Tensor product:
tensored_state = state1 ^ state2

# Or equivalently:
tensored_state = state1.tensor(state2)

# Print the result:
from qiskit.visualization import array_to_latex
array_to_latex(tensored_state, max_size = 16)
```